# Ajax issue with WebGate/OAM

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am in progress of integrating my application with OAM where I am facing an issue with AJAX call using XMLHttpRequest. The intermediate JSP used on ajax is set as uprotected. Now when I make an ajax call while not being logged in OAM, I get the response as 302 Found and I see one more request to https://host/oam/server/obrareq.cgi?xyz which is 302 Moved Temporarily  and status code as 0. When I try doing the same call while being logged on to OAM, the response is proper and status comes to be 200. Please advise.

Comment: Did you solve this by now?